# Why I can't connect to postgresql with codeigniter?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, pdo

I knew there are similar question, but I still can get solution.

If I set `dbdriver` to `pdo`, it showed `could not find driver`. But, if it's `postgre`, I got `Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()`.

[image: database.php]

Can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using PDO in dbdriver like this, don't use DSN :

```
$db['default']['port'] = 5432;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=kasir';
$db['default']['username'] = 'admin_kasir';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'kasir';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
```

Hope this help you out.